# set sum formula in excel using vba

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

Working on a excel macros where I am trying to add the cell values from above cells to calculate total value. This is what my data looks like[image: Sample Excel Document]

Here I want to add above cell values for each column to calculate the sum. To accomplish this i have written a macro as follows.

```
For cl = 2 To 5    
    Worksheets(5).Cells(4, cl).Formula = "=SUM(B4:B6)"        
Next cl
```

This should set the formula to each cell in a row till 5 columns.
But it sets the same formula on all cells in a row it should get change according to column. How to set sum formula for each cell for corresponding column ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand your code. You seem to be writing into row 4, but you also want to sum from row 4 to row 6. That will create a circular reference.

Let's assume the formula is written into row 3 instead. You will want to use the R1C1 reference style to make the cells to sum relative to the current cells.

A trick to learn what reference to use is:

- Get a new worksheet, enter `=SUM(B4:B6)` into cell B3 and copy to the right.
- Then click *File > Options > Formulas* and select **R1C1 Reference Style**.
- Now inspect the formulas in the sheet. You will see this: `=SUM(R[1]C:R[3]C)`

This is what you need in the macro.

```
For cl = 2 To 5    
    Worksheets(5).Cells(3, cl).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[1]C:R[3]C)"    
Next cl
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use very simple formula like below:

```
Sub sum_month()
Sheets("13").Activate
Range("D2").Formula = "=SUM(A1+A2+A3)"
End Sub
```

And next just hold and drag the cell to fill up another rows automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, you can use this:

```
For cl = 2 To 5
    ColName = Left(Cells(1, cl).Address(0, 0), (Cells(1, cl).Column < 27) + 2)
    ValueSum = "=SUM(" & ColName & "4:" & ColName & "6)"
    Worksheets(5).Cells(4, cl).Formula = ValueSum
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

some more details to R1C1 and R[1]C[1] style in formulas.
As far as I know R[1]C[1] creates a relative reference and R1C1 creates a absolute reference. But keep in mind that the figures for R[x] and C[y] are an offset to the cell which contains the formula.

That means if you want to show the sum of A1:B4 in C5 the code has to be like this:

```
Worksheets(5).Cells(5, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C[-2]:R[-1]C[-1])"
```

If you want to the same but ending up with an absolute reference is aht to look like this.

```
 Worksheets(5).Cells(5, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C1:R4C2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
For cl = 2 To 5
    ColName = Left(Cells(1, cl).Address(False, False), 1 - (cl > 26))
    Worksheets(5).Cells(4, cl).Formula = "=SUM(" & ColName & "4:" & ColName & "6)"
Next cl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just reference the whole formula range and Excel will be smart enough to adjust the columns.

With no loop:

Worksheets(5).Cells(4, cl).resize(1,4).Formula = "=SUM(B4:B6)"